# Activex Combobox Not Selectable After Rows Unhidden

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have searched for a while now and dont see a solution to my issue.  I have several activex comboboxes on a worksheet.  For instant there are 5 Comboboxes in rows 1-5.  The user clicks a button that is linked to a userform which will hide or unhide the 5 rows based on the users input.  Hidding the 5 rows is not issue using vba.  The problem that I am facing is when the 5 rows are unhidden, the comboboxes are non-selectable.  What i mean is the user cant select or begin typing anything into them.  They are visible but almost like an invisible object is over them so a user cannot select them.

Making a copy of the worksheet or selecting "design mode" and moving the boxes slightly, the comboboxes are selectable again.  I dont want to keep copying sheets and I haven't found a way to move the comboboxes accurately outside of design-mode.  Below is vba code I was trying to use to move the box but using -11 and 11 would just move the box up both times.

Anyone know why activex comboboxes get "locked" after they rows they are in become unhidden or have a solution?

ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").IncrementTop 11

Comment: What will be a result if you add a line `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes("ComboBox1").Enabled` to the code which unhides rows?

Comment: Thanks for the response, using that code, i get run time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior. I't better that you share the code that hides and unhides rows.

Comment: Below is my code, its very basic.  I have the same issue when using the group by + and - options in the excel ribbon.                                                                
 Private Sub generic_g_Click()

ActiveSheet.Rows("39:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Unload Me

End Sub

Comment: I still can't replicate that. Do you use a userform for this?

Comment: no userform is used and originally I was not using a macro to hide the rows either.  I was using the group function in date-outline in the excel ribbon.  Also manually hiding the cells and manually unhiding returns the same outcome.  I find it weird that the boxes become usable after moving them while in design mode or copying the sheet.

Comment: `Unload Me` is used to unload a form. That is from the code you provided in previous comment. I suggest you to [edit your question appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a sample of workbook  where comboboxes are "frozen"

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, using Excel 2019.

I don't know the cause, but I found a workable solution.

First, to also declare my specific problem:

I have a drop-down activex list, through which if "Option 1" is chosen, it hides many rows as well as ComboBox1 , but if "Option 2" is selected, then it shows these rows and the Combobox1.
So, when "Option 2" is called after "Option 1", the desired rows are visible, while ComboBox1 is visible but unselectable.

My solution is that I added a positional statement in the drop down list's code, in case of "Option 2" selected. As following:

```
ComboBox1.Top = 75  # or wherever you want it to be (trial&error)
ComboBox1.Left = 410 # or wherever you want it to be (trial&error)
```